How do I change my SUMO option --collision.action from the default value "teleport" to "none"?
I need to set SUMO (Simulation of Urban Mobility) so that no action is taken when vehicle collisions occur. To do this, I need to change the --collision.action option, which by default has value "teleport" (which is not good for my purposes) to "none", but I do not understand where (and by writing what) among the various SUMO files, I can set this option. Maybe I have to change something in the sumoConfigurations.xsd file? and what should i write? i don't know XML very well...
I tried moving through the various files that appear in the directory where I installed sumo but I couldn't figure out where to set the options
